# Display message from url in android

Tags: android, message

I need to display message and name using URL in Text view in android application. How can i do that. Please guide me a sample code/link.

Thanks.

Comment: Please could you explain what exactly you would like to do?

Comment: I need data from a url to get displayed in a textview. String urlname = "http://xxxxx/xxxxx/xx" , and display that message in textview in my application. Sample code is needed.

Comment: @user1083389 - Be more specific and show us what you've tried. Are you struggling to get the data from the URL? Or strugglying to show what you got from the URL? In either case show us what you tried and what it does.

Comment: My issue is i am working with Fb app for Android application. Normally we get JSON as response. But i am getting HTML <div class ="abcd"> ...(For example). I need to display image from url which i am able to do. Now i need to display Name of the user, message from the user in textview. How can i get values from these html <div> classes and display the corresponding values in corresponding fields. sample CODE IS: http://pastebin.com/YHnU9Kbq

Answer (score 0):

You should use an AsyncTask to get the data you need from the specified URL and then parse it and show it.

Read about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

//do u want like this

```
if(!url_text.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    textView.setText("");
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url_text.getText().toString());
                    // Get the response
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    String response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
                    textView.setText(response_str);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL String empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Comment: My issue is i am working with Fb app for Android application. Normally we get JSON as response. But i am getting HTML <div class ="abcd"> ...(For example). I need to display image from url which i am able to do. Now i need to display Name of the user, message from the user in textview. How can i get values from these html <div> classes and display the corresponding values in corresponding fields. sample CODE IS: http://pastebin.com/YHnU9Kbq